# Dynamically initialize a UIViewController subclass and create its instances

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to build a simple vehicle management application as part of my college assignment. I apologise in advance if my query is too basic as I am new to programming.
So, the questions are

1. How to initialize a **UIViewController** subclass **dynamically**?
2. All my variables are to be entered by user on different storyboard scenes in **UITextField** bars and are being passed on to next classes through **prepareForSegue()** func
3. I want to create a new vehicle every time the user enters data of a new vehicle and then I want all the vehicles on my **TableViewController** subclass scene in **storyboard**.

Your help shall be extremely appreciated. Please consider the screenshot of the subclass for which I want to create instances.

Thanks and Regards
[Final Sub Class which is to be dynamically instantiated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tegXE.png)

```
class SelectVehicleViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate
{   
var vehName = String()
var vehVIN = String()
var engineType = String()
var engineCapacity = String()
var manufacturingYear = String()
var odometerDistance = Int()

var engineOil = Int()
var transmissionOil = Int()
var powerSteeringOil = Int()
var brakeOil = Int()
var coolant = Int()
var engineAirFilter = Int()
var engineOilFilter = Int()
var fuelFilter = Int()
var fuelInjectors = Int()
var cabinAirFilter = Int()
var timingBelt = Int()
var accessoryBelt = Int()

var setupLastRefuelling = Int()

init(vehName: String, vehVIN: String, engineType: String, engineCapacity: String, manufacturingYear: String, odometerDistance: Int,
    engineOil: Int, transmissionOil: Int, powerSteeringOil: Int, brakeOil: Int, coolant: Int, engineAirFilter: Int, engineOilFilter: Int,
    fuelFilter: Int, fuelInjectors: Int, cabinAirFilter: Int, timingBelt: Int, accessoryBelt: Int,‹ setupLastRefuelling: Int)
{

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
// Create an object of the data received from Summary Scene in SelectVehicle Scene

//var vehicleArray: [SelectVehicleViewController] = []

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

    //Setting up the table view in Vehicle Selector Scene

 //    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{ return vehicleArray.count}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    //cell.textLabel?.text = vehicleArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you could include the relevant `code` in your question with appropriate formatting instead of in form of a screenshot. Reproducing problems from screenshots is not feasible. Also, you might want to check out how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to better describe your issue.

Comment: I have added the code sir! Kindly help me. Thanks